# DB2: Create Function - Scale

Tags: function, db2, scale

i have a table popo:

No|Id|Values.

1|X|321225.4775   -> Scale:4.

2|Y|321235.2115   -> Scale:4.

3|Z|12123.12321   -> Scale:5.

4|A|              -> NULL.

5|B|12321         -> Scale:0.

i want to Flaging when column "Values" have a data where scale > 4.
below is my current function script.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
FUNCTION "SCHEME"."VALIDATION01" (A VARCHAR(500)) RETURNS INT
LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
DECLARE ASD DEC;
DECLARE A DEC;
SET ASD = CAST(A AS DEC(20,4));
IF A = ASD THEN RETURN NULL;
ELSEIF A IS NULL THEN RETURN NULL;
ELSE RETURN 1;
END IF;
END
```

Output:

```
[null]
[null]
[null]
[null]
[null]
```

i want output is:

```
[null]
[null]
1
[null]
[null]
```

can you help me?

Comment: This smells like an [X/Y Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).  Why do you need this information?  What are you planning on doing with it?  Why is the input parameter a string-type?  If this is operating over a table, is it possible to just truncate or round the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
FUNCTION "SCHEME"."VALIDATION01" (A VARCHAR(500)) RETURNS INT
LANGUAGE SQL
RETURN CASE WHEN A <> DEC(A, 20, 4) THEN 1 END;
```

The `CASE` statement returns 1, if A `IS NOT NULL` AND the original value is not equal to this value casted to the `DECIMAL(20, 4)` data type. It returns `NULL` otherwise.
It's the user's responsibility to call this function with proper string parameter to avoid string to number data type conversion errors.

Comment: thank you, it works fine! can you explain the code? I use varchar because I get the source is worth varchar

Comment: @TsabitAbdullah I've added an explanation.